# Matching up line numbers from log file to function's code

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, pgadmin

I have an error I'm trying to debug in a trigger function. In the Postgres log, I have the following:

```
2012-08-16 21:41:23 PDT ERROR:  Unknown period: D
2012-08-16 21:41:23 PDT CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "handle_promotion_update" 
    line 60  at assignment
SQL statement "UPDATE promotion SET some_column = foo + 1
    WHERE id = NEW.promotion_id"
PL/pgSQL function "handle_new_reward" line 94 at SQL statement
```

So, it seems like my problem probably starts at "line 60"

My question, is where do the line numbers start?  If I go in pgAdmin and look at the function declaration it has "helper" (like delete function) at the top. So, I don't think it's from there. But, does it include the function declaration? Or is it just from the line with `BEGIN`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Line numbers that you see in the PostgreSQL server logs start at the line with the *opening quotes* of the function body. You have to add the lines before that to arrive at the absolute line number in the pgAdmin SQL editor.

Don't get confused: if you have errors while trying to create a function you get different line numbers: they refer to the executed script as a whole, while line numbers in runtime errors refer to the function body.

Comment: Hi Erwin...  follow up here.  Am I correct to assume that the "opening quote" is line 1?  It's a 1-based numbering.  Correct?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, What do you mean by "opening quote"?  I've never seen a " at the beginning of my function before.

Comment: @danjuggler: The function body is a plain text string. It either starts with a single quote or, more commonly, with dollar-quoting. Details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/12172353/939860 Aside: I never mentioned double quotes (`"`).

Comment: `||||| ||||| ||||| |||| ||||| ||` <-- Number of times Erwin has schooled me.