# What are '$$' used for in PL/pgSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, plpgsql, dollar-sign, dollar-quoting

Being completely new to PL/pgSQL, what is the meaning of double dollar signs in [this function](http://postgres.cz/wiki/PL/pgSQL_%28en%29):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_phone_number(text)
RETURNS boolean AS $$
BEGIN
  IF NOT $1 ~  e'^\\+\\d{3}\\ \\d{3} \\d{3} \\d{3}$' THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Wrong formated string "%". Expected format is +999 999';
  END IF;
  RETURN true; 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT IMMUTABLE;
```

I'm guessing that, in `RETURNS boolean AS $$`, `$$` is a placeholder.

The last line is a bit of a mystery: `$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT IMMUTABLE;`

By the way, what does the last line mean?

Comment: Please consider marking Erwin response as answer to this question, his description explains what actually are `$$` and you can learn something new by reading it e.g. there is also `$foo$`

Answer (score 228, accepted):

These dollar signs (`$$`) are used for [**dollar quoting**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING), which is **in no way specific to function definitions**. It can be used to replace single quotes enclosing string literals (constants) anywhere in SQL scripts.

The body of a function happens to be such a string literal. Dollar quoting is a PostgreSQL-specific substitute for single quotes to avoid escaping of nested single quotes (recursively). You can enclose the function body in single-quotes just as well. But then you have to escape all nested single quotes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_phone_number(text)
  RETURNS boolean
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT IMMUTABLE AS
'
BEGIN
  IF NOT $1 ~  e''^\\+\\d{3}\\ \\d{3} \\d{3} \\d{3}$'' THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION ''Malformed string: "%". Expected format is +999 999'', $1;
  END IF;
  RETURN true; 
END
';
```

(Added the missing parameter for `RAISE`, btw.)

This isn't such a good idea. Use dollar-quoting instead. More specifically, also put a (meaningful) token inside the `$$` to avoid confusion with nested quotes in the function body. A common case, actually.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_phone_number(text)
  RETURNS boolean  
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT IMMUTABLE AS
$func$
BEGIN
 ...
END
$func$;
```

See:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

To your second question:
Read the most excellent [manual on `CREATE FUNCTION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) to understand the last line of your example.

Comment: You're supposed to say *fine manual*, RTEM just doesn't have the right ring to it :)

Comment: @muistooshort: My bad, trying a variation on the theme seems to have broken the harmony. How do you like RTMEM? :)

Comment: I tried yelling it and it just wasn't the same. Although, there are some situations where politeness counts.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Okay, but what is `$body$`? From `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_ts() RETURNS  TRIGGER AS $BODY$ BEGIN NEW.updated_at = NOW(); RETURN NEW; END; $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql` - I don't see `body` defined anywhere. I really have no idea what is going on here

Comment: @Growler: `$body$` is just "dollar-quoting", like I explained. More details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860

Comment: Thanks for that man, faced with a strange behavior creating PG function via Terraform and using $$. Change to single quotes has helped.

Comment: I'm getting an exception. "No function body specified"

Comment: @MA1 I can't reproduce that exception. Fixed an unrelated syntax error in `RAISE` that I had copied from the OP, though.

Answer (score 27):

The `$$` is a delimiter you use to indicate where the function definition starts and ends. Consider the following,

```
CREATE TABLE <name> <definition goes here> <options go here, eg: WITH OIDS>
```

The create function syntax is similar, but because you are going to use all sorts of SQL in your function (especially the end of statement `;` character), the parser would trip if you didn't delimit it. So you should read your statement as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_phone_number(text)
RETURNS boolean AS <code delimited by $$> LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT IMMUTABLE;
```

The stuff after the actual definition are options to give the database more information about your function, so it can optimize its usage.

In fact, if you look under ["4.1.2.4. Dollar-Quoted String Constants"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) in the manual, you will see that you can even use characters in between the dollar symbols and it will all count as one delimiter.

Comment: As stated in the correct answer, this is inaccurate, double dollar signs delimit a constant string and are not specific to functions.

Answer (score 1):

The delimiters [$$](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) and ['](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS) are used to create the body which can have one or more SQL statements in a [SQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html), [PL/pgSQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html), [procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/xproc.html), [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/triggers.html) and [event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createeventtrigger.html).

For example, you can create a [PL/pgSQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) with the delimiter `$$` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION addition(v1 INTEGER, v2 INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
DECLARE
  result INTEGER;
BEGIN
SELECT v1 + v2 INTO result;
RETURN result;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And, you can create a PL/pgSQL function with the delimiter `'` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION addition(v1 INTEGER, v2 INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER AS '
DECLARE
  result INTEGER;
BEGIN
SELECT v1 + v2 INTO result;
RETURN result;
END;
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```