# User Defined Functions returning Tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create a UDF which returns a table containing four values:

```
CREATE TABLE ts_table
(
  id character varying, 
  year integer, 
  rank double precision, 
  votes integer
);
```

Then, using a UDF, I have to return a table defined by (something along the lines of):

```
CREATE FUNCTION ts_myfunc(text) RETURNS SETOF ts_table AS $$
    'SELECT id,year,rank,votes FROM productions NATURAL JOIN directors NATURAL JOIN ratings WHERE attr is NULL AND pid=$1 ORDER BY year;'
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

However, when I try to create the UDF with that command, I get

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'SELECT id,year,rank,votes FROM productions NATURAL JOIN directors NATURAL JOIN ratings WHERE attr is NULL AND pid=$1 ORDER BY year;'"
LINE 2: 'SELECT id,year,rank,votes FROM productions NATURAL JOIN dir...
```

Comment: Read up on ["dollar-quoting"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING). This closely related question may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144284/what-are-used-for-in-pl-pgsql/12172353#12172353

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thanks, I noticed my mistake a little too late but I figured I'd leave it as an answer to future, similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the line 
`'SELECT id,year,rank,votes FROM productions NATURAL JOIN directors NATURAL JOIN ratings WHERE attr is NULL AND pid=$1 ORDER BY year;'`

to

`SELECT id,year,rank,votes FROM productions NATURAL JOIN directors NATURAL JOIN ratings WHERE attr is NULL AND pid=$1 ORDER BY year;`

(remove the single quotes) will solve the problem.