# Validate column using regular expression in postgre SQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

I need to check whether a column in a table having a numeric value followed by decimal point and 3 precisions after the decimal point. Kindly suggest how to do using regular expression in postgre SQL (or) any other alternate method.

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The basic regex for digits, a period and digits is `\d+\.\d{3}`

You can use it for several things, for instance:

**1. Add a Constraing to your Column Definition**

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD (CONSTRAINT mycolumn_regexp CHECK (mycolumn ~ $$^\d+\.\d{3}\Z$$));
```

**2. Find Rows that Don't Match**

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn !~ $$^\d+\.\d{3}\Z$$;
```

**3. Find Rows that Match**

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn ~ $$^\d+\.\d{3}\Z$$;
```

Comment: Is my understanding correct, that a single quote (`'`) could've been used instead of `$$`, because they are interchangeable? (from [What are '$$' used for in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144284/what-are-used-for-in-pl-pgsql) and [4.1.2.4. Dollar-Quoted String Constants](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING).)

Comment: The link from the PostgreSQL manual that helped me decipher the matching part: [9.7.3. POSIX Regular Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) in "9.7 Pattern Matching".