# What is the difference between these two types of functions?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a difference between these two functions?

1st:

```
CREATE FUNCTION sales_tax(subtotal real) RETURNS real AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN subtotal * 0.06;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

2nd:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sales_tax(subtotal real) RETURNS real  AS
$BODY$
begin
    RETURN subtotal * 0.06;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Why does one have `$$` and the other one have `$body$`? (PostgreSQL)
[What are '$$' used for in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144284/what-are-used-for-in-pl-pgsql) is not an answer to my question. is explains what is `$` in general, and it doesn't refer to `$body$`

maybe one of them was the way to go in older versions and it might be depricit in future releases?

Comment: @choz this is not answering my question. there is nothing about $body$ there.

Comment: Read [Erwin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12172353/1627271), might give you some clue.

Comment: @java: `$$` and `$body$` are different versions of the same thing

Comment: @java: Yes there is; the second answer (the one with the highest score, but not the accepted answer) explicitly says why you might well want to use a word such as `$BODY$` in place of a plain `$$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real difference.  You choose your 'end of function' marker after the keyword `AS` with '$$ quoting'.  In the first case, the chosen marker is `$$`; in the second, it is `$BODY$`.  There's no other significant difference; the language is case-insensitive for keywords.

Answer (score 4):

They are equivalent; both `$$...$$` and `$foo$...$foo$` are [dollar-quoted string constants](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING). (The `foo` part is optional; it just lets you end the string exactly where you want to, in case your string actually contains `$$`.)

Answer (score 0):

The functions themselves are identical: as has been pointed out, the only difference is the closing tag.

The declarations of the functions are different though: the `CREATE FUNCTION` declaration will not overwrite an existing function with the same name, while `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` will.