# How to exit PSQL CREATE FUNCTION screens

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, psql

I'm new to writing functions in Postgres..

I don't want to exit PSQL entirely, (I know CTRL+D will do that,) but I seem to be stuck in the CREATE FUNCTION screen.

```
mattswheels=# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 99_cents(money)
mattswheels-#  RETURNS money
mattswheels-#  LANGUAGE plpgsql
mattswheels-#  LEAKPROOF
mattswheels-# AS $function$
mattswheels$# DECLARE
mattswheels$#     new_price money;
mattswheels$#     size int;
mattswheels$# BEGIN
mattswheels$#     size := char_length(money);
mattswheels$#     RETURN size;
mattswheels$# END;
mattswheels$# 
mattswheels$# \q
mattswheels$# halp
mattswheels$# ;
mattswheels$# ;
mattswheels$# ;
mattswheels$# ;
mattswheels$# help
mattswheels$# ;
mattswheels$# \?
```

Comment: note : your `$function$` dollar quoting has not yet ended.

Comment: Well how do I end it?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createfunction.html

Comment: [What are '$$' used for in PL/pgSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12172353/939860)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I figured out that postgres functions can't start with a number.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ".99"
LINE 1: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.99cents(money)
```

Secondly, to exit out of the issue above the `$function$` declaration needed to be closed with this:

```
$function$;
```

As far as I can tell, there is no other keystroke that can exit one out of the CREATE FUNCTION screen, unless PSQL is exited entirely with CTRL+D.

Answer (score 1):

Try CTRL+C. It discards last query with not terminated quotes.