# Declare "LANGUAGE plpgsql" before or after the function body?

Tags: postgresql, syntax, plpgsql, user-defined-functions, quotes

Is there any difference between:

```
CREATE FUNCTION func() RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
    declare
    begin
      -- do something
    end
$$;
```

and

```
CREATE FUNCTION func() RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
    declare
    begin
      -- do something
    end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Does `LANGUAGE plpgsql` basically just have to be outside the scope of the `$$` usage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No difference whatsoever.**
The function body is a string literal. The `$$` are just dollar-quotes and could be single quotes, too (but better use dollar quotes!):

- [What are '$$' used for in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144284/what-are-used-for-in-pl-pgsql/12172353#12172353)
- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

`CREATE FUNCTION` is a declarative SQL-DDL command, and the order of keywords is pretty free, as per [definition in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html). (Key words within the curly braces in the command definition can be arranged freely, but not the rest).

I eventually settled on always putting the language declaration on top with the rest of the function header, before the function body. Makes more sense.