# Unable to create a PG sql function

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a function in Posgresql which returns a table:

```
create or replace function my_func1(var1 integer, var2 integer[], var3 integer)
  returns table(col1 integer, col2 integer, col3 timestamp) 
as

begin

    select  .........
end;
language sql;
```

It says:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "begin"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
create or replace function my_func1(var1 integer, var2 integer[], var3 integer)
returns table(col1 integer, col2 integer, col3 timestamp) 
as
$func$
begin
    return query 
    select  .........
end;
$func$
language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `begin` in an [`SQL` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html). Did you mean to create a [`plpgsql` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-structure.html)?

Then use `LANGUAGE plpgsql` instead.
And enclose the function body in quotes either way, it's text - preferably dollar quotes:

- [What are '$$' used for in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144284/what-are-used-for-in-pl-pgsql?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: where should I place "$func$" in the end of a function: before or after `language plpgsql;`?

Comment: @Torito: please see the examples in the manual. [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-EXAMPLES) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#AEN65553)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I don't need to.

Comment: @Torito: then why did you ask "where should I place.."? That is clearly answered in the manual.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, no.

Comment: @Torito: it **is** shown in the links I gave you. But if you don't want to read the manual, at least read the linked answer from Erwin. He explained in great length what that is and how to use it

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, no, he didn't.

Comment: Database expert, how about my question?

Comment: @Torito: You can place  `LANGUAGE plpgsql` before or after the function body, makes no difference. But not *inside*, obviously.