# Bind values for query with plpgsql in Yii2

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, yii2, plpgsql

I execute SQL query with Yii2 DAO.

```
$db->createCommand("
  DO $$
  DECLARE
    rec RECORD;
    pos INT := 0;
  BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE "type" = :t LOOP
      UPDATE table1    SET position = pos    WHERE id = rec.id;
      pos := pos + 2;
    END LOOP;
  END;
  $$ language 'plpgsql'
", [':t' => 0])->execute();
```

But it fails with error:

> ```
> SQLSTATE[42P18]: Indeterminate datatype: 7
> ERROR:  could not determine data type of parameter $1
> ```

`type` column has `INT` type. I tried to set param type explicitly with `[':t' => [0, \PDO::PARAM_INT]]`. But the error is still here. If I concatenate the value right into the SQL string, it works, but that's not a solution. `:t` is only one parameter in this query.

Other simple SQL queries work successfully. This problem exists only for queries with procedures. If I run this query from the DataGrip, it works. But in PHP it fails.

Why does it not work and how can I bind params for such queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [create an actual function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) and call it, you can pass *values* as parameters.

But while you execute a [`DO` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html), the function body (enclosed in dollar-quotes `$$` in your example) is just a **string literal**. No parameter passing and nothing returned. You would have to *concatenate* values as strings into the plpgsql code.

But you don't need either. Use a simple **prepared statement** instead. Much cheaper than looping anyway:

```
UPDATE table1 t
SET    position = t1.pos
FROM  (
   SELECT id, (row_number() OVER () - 1) * 2 AS pos 
   FROM   table1
   WHERE  "type" = :t
   ) t1
WHERE  t.id = t1.id
```

It's trivial to pass a parameter value now.

Aside: The result is arbitrary, unless you add `ORDER BY` to the `OVER` clause. That weakness is in your original, too.

Related:

- [What are '$$' used for in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144284/what-are-used-for-in-pl-pgsql/12172353#12172353)

Comment: Thank you for a full explanation!