# Executing psql command with dollar quoting

Tags: postgresql, psql

I just learned about the meaning of [dollar-quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12172353/3271380) in PostgreSQL. Now I was wondering, how would I handle dollar-quoting when executing an SQL statement from psql commandline?

If possible, I would like to avoid using escaping with single quotes.

The statement I want to execute looks something like this:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -d db_name -c "CREATE FUNCTION my_function(name text)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
        ...
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;"
```

But I get a `syntax error at or near "$"` and don't know how to handle this. I couldn't find any hint out there.

Comment: That's probably `bash` expanding your dollars as variables. Try using single quotes (`-c 'CREATE ...`) or escaping the dollars (`\$BODY\$`)

Comment: Wow, nice. That escaping with back-slash seems to work!

Comment: This kind of problems can be avoided if you put the SQL into a script file and then run it using `psql -f create.sql` that is much more reliable. Plus: you can put that DDL script under version control as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I will probably do this, which also came to my mind right now. I have the code unter version control anyway but that way will be much cleaner.