# Print messages in postgresql

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell, unix

I am writing a BASH Shell Script to execute one SELECT query on postgreSQL and also print a custom message before the SELECT Query o/p.

FYI...

```
PGPASSWORD=XXXXX psql --host=XXX --port=5432 --username=XXXXX --dbname=XXXXX << EOF

        DO language plpgsql $$
        BEGIN
        raise notice 'USER';
        END
        $$;
        SELECT email,username,count(*) FROM users GROUP BY username,email HAVING count(*) > 1;


EOF
```

But this is throwing ERROR, as it replaces `$$` with the PID. How can i resolve this. What can i use instead of `$$`.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the `$$`? E.g., `\$\$`?

Comment: Alternatively, use single quotes instead of double dollar signs. (See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144284/what-are-used-for-in-pl-pgsql .)

Comment: Thanks..! it works.
But is there any other way we can print messages apart form raise notice..!?

Comment: `echo "message"`?