# ? is not replacing with the values inside $$

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have the procedure where i want to pass the exact values from jdbc that is passed from user after query format.

but when i am using preparedstatement with $$ it gives me an error saying :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 3, number of columns: 2.
```

however without $$ it's working perfectly fine.please help me how to pass argument with $$ with preparestatement?

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password);
String prepareselectSQL="SELECT get_sum(?,?,$$?$$)";
stmt=conn.prepareStatement(prepareselectSQL);
stmt.setInt(1,10);
stmt.setInt(2,200);
stmt.setString(3,"");
rs = stmt.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
      System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
```

see below is my example query:

```
select  * from getdashboarddata_010('application','(upload + download)',?,'2018-02-05 00:00:00','2018-02-05 00:00:00','0','5-1','','hits','desc','','true');
```

below is the value which needs to replace with ? :

```
(select * ,  ''::text as srczonename, ''::text as srczonetype, ''::text as firewall_cat_type, ''::text as destzonename, ''::text as destzonetype ,  null::int as appresolver from fwapp_applicationutfv5_12hr ) fwapp_applicationutfv5_12hr where "5mintime" >='2018-05-04 00:00:00' and "5mintime" < '2018-05-04 23:59:59'
```

so,you can see my value already contains single quotes for that reason i  need to pass this with dollar quoting within prepare statement.

Comment: what does `$$` mean?

Comment: @YCF_L actually my query is containing $$,as $$ signifies in postgres , the exact way like single quotes should pass.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144284/what-are-used-for-in-pl-pgsql

Comment: Try `'?'` ($$ seems to be the **P/SQL** delimiter) and remove setString. This should work. Otherwise leave `?` and do `stmt.setString(3, "?")`

Comment: Placeholders should never be quoted. Neither with single quotes, nor with dollar quoting

Comment: "*for that reason i need to pass this with dollar quoting*" - no you do not need to do that. The `PreparedStatement` will do the work for you. Simply remove those quotes and everything will work just fine

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to use a "dollar quoted" string literal, and substitute a parameter into the string.  You cannot do that a `?` inside an SQL string literal.  Within the SQL string literal, the dollar character is not recognized as a parameter placeholder.  (It is just an ordinary literal dollar character ... in the string.)

If you need to do something that entails assembling a string value, you should you should do the assembly in Java.  Something like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT get_sum(?, ?, ?)";
stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setInt(1, 10);
stmt.setInt(2, 200);
stmt.setString(3, "'" + someString + "'");
```

The above will pass a string value that starts and ends with the `'` character to the SQL `get_sum` stored procedure.

Comment: that somevalue already contains single quotes and it is formatted with messageformat.so one occurance of single quote gets disappear.after whatever is remained i need to pass as it is.so i need $$ in place of single quotes

Comment: I don't think that is correct.  Please amend your question with an MCVE that demonstrates that behavior.  I would be very, very surprised if Postgres is stripping quotes from a string that is passed via a `?` and `setString`.

Comment: @AshaKoshti: no you don't need that - that's precisely what a `PreparedStatement` is for: you don't have to worry about escaping embedded single quotes in your values. All you need is `SELECT get_sum(?, ?, ?)` and then `setString(3, someString)` - regardless of what `someString` contains

Comment: @StephenC i have updated the question.you can see that

Comment: Your updates don't make sense to me.  Sorry.  You appear to be trying to use `?` to insert SQL into SQL.  You can't do that.