# What is `AS $$` in sql functions?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dollar-quoting

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION one() RETURNS integer AS $$
    SELECT 1 AS result;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

why i cant write like this:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION one() RETURNS integer
    SELECT 1 AS result;
```

- what is `AS $$`?
- what is `$$ LANGUAGE SQL`?
- what is `$$`?

Comment: omg, `$` is alias for quotes =) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144284/what-are-used-for-in-pl-pgsql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PostgreSQL it is a feature called dollar-quoting, which allows you to include a body of text without escaping the single quotes

Using it as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hello_world(param_your_name text)
RETURNS text AS
$$
SELECT 'Hello world. My name is ' || param_your_name || '.';
$$
language sql STRICT;
```

which is easier to read than

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hello_world(param_your_name text)
RETURNS text AS
'
SELECT ''Hello world. My name is '' || param_your_name || ''.'';
'
language sql STRICT;
```

Read more here - https://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/376-Dollar-quoting-for-escaping-single-quotes.html