# Restructuring JSON Data While Saving Characters Escape Format

Tags: python, sql, json, postgresql

I am getting a JSON response from a server, in order to arrange and clean the data I am restructuring the response.
When I send the data back to a Postgresql DB, I get an error for entries like `place's`

I understand that in SQL it should be written as `place''s` and not as `place\'s`

How can I load and work with JSON data without changing this property?

For example, I am trying the following query:

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (111, 'name', "Dana place's")
```

As it interpreted by PostgreSQL into `Dana place/'s`

Comment: Instead of single quotes use [dollar quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144284/what-are-used-for-in-pl-pgsql) (see the accepted answer) or the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS).

Comment: @Stefanov.sm f"$$value$$" leaves the entry with the dollar signs in the DB

Comment: No, dollar-quote the _whole_ query text 'as is' w/o touching the single quotes.

Comment: you can use the `quote_nullable()` function see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-string.html)

Comment: @Stefanov.sm `f"$$INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (111, 'name', "Dana place's")
$$"`?

Comment: Sorry, my suggestion is wrong. Pls. ignore it.