# PSQL passing external variables

Tags: postgresql, parameter-passing, plpgsql, psql

I'm trying to pass a value/variable from a batch script to a SQL script and I am having trouble.

The code flows as such:

Starting in my batch script, I make a psql command call referencing `myFirstSQLFile.sql`, and passing `env` as a variable with a value of `test`

```
%PSQLCOMMAND% -h {server} -U {user} -d {dbname} -E -q -f myFirstSQLFile.sql -v env="test"
```

In my `myFirstSQLFile.sql`, it makes references to a number of other sql files, but I'll just show one for simplicity. It is in this file that I know I can access my `env` variable by using `:env`

```
\i myLastSQLFile.sql;
```

Within `myLastSQLFile.sql`, I have sql code that is meant to use that external `env` var for conditional statements as below

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN
   IF :env = 'test' THEN
       # Do Something
   END IF;
END
$do$
```

I know outside of those `$do$` tags, I can access my variable by using the notation `:env`, However within them I cannot. I don't really understand what the `$do$` tags or the `BEGIN/END` block are for and if/how I can access my `env` variable within them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`DO` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) executes an anonymous code block. The *"$do$ tags"* are dollar-quotes. Read this first to understand:

- [What are '$$' used for in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144284/what-are-used-for-in-pl-pgsql/12172353#12172353)

`BEGIN`and `END` are decorators for a [PL/pgSQL code block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) - which is the default PL (programming language) of a `DO` statement.

psql does not interpolate variables *inside* quoted SQL literals and identifiers.

*One* way to fix your problem is using Postgres string processing and then execute the result with `\gexec`. From psql:

```sql
SELECT format($$
DO
$do$
BEGIN
   IF %L = 'test' THEN
      -- do something
   END IF;
END
$do$;
$$, :'env')\gexec
```

There are various other ways. Maybe a (temporary) function can serve you better: you can pass parameters to it. Depends on the complete picture.
See this answers to a very similar question on dba.SE:

- [How to pass variable to PL/pgSQL code from the command line?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/240542/3684)