Unhelpful syntax error at end of input PostgreSQL in Rust SQLx migrations
Yes there are hundreds of questions like this one, however, they all have different syntax errors. Postgres's syntax check is not giving me any hints on this one. The insert statements work fine, syntactically if I replace the ID with a fake constant. My error is in how I've added the do $$ declare begin end $$ construct here.
do $$
declare new_inspection_template_id uuid;
begin

insert into inspection_template
  (name, revision, description, product, notes)
values (
  'QUAL349 RevC',
  1,  
  'Quality checks for beveling.',
  'sheet',
  'There are no notes.'
) returning inspection_template_id into new_inspection_template_id;

insert into workflow (station, inspection_template_id)
values ('beveling', new_inspection_template_id);

end $$; 

Running this in my Rust-sqlx migration, like so:
sqlx::migrate!().run(&mut dbc).await?;

This code is running several inserts and creates in multiple files found in the ./migrations directory as is the default.
I get this error

error: while executing migrations: error returned from database: syntax error at end of input

Version:

psql (PostgreSQL) 15.6 (Ubuntu 15.6-0ubuntu0.23.10.1)

I also gave this a try and I get the exact same syntax error at end of input
with temp as (
  insert into inspection_template
    (name, revision, description, product, notes)
  values (
    'QUAL349 RevC',
    1,  
    'Quality checks for beveling.',
    'sheet',
    'There are no notes.'
  ) returning inspection_template_id
)
insert into workflow (station, inspection_template_id)
select 'beveling', inspection_template_id from temp;


@JGH PostgreSQL doesn't care about that last semicolon: demo. OP's code is syntactically fine, but something's probably messing with the $$ along the way. @mmachenry Have you tried swapping those out for named dollar quotes? $f$ You could also swap those out for regular single quotes ' and duplicate those inside the do block body: demo2

Same issue with both. Perhaps this is a quoting issue in the Rust migration platform and I should update with Rust topics?

I would turn on logging in the database and look at what is actually sent to PostgreSQL.

Add to question text Rust Postgres driver being used and the actual Rust code being used.

I added the info.

Do you need a semicolon after "end"?

@RichardHuxton: The semicolon after END is optional.

Your SQL and PL/pgSQL code is flawless.  Is $ a special character in Rust? Try escaping like: do \$do\$ declare begin ... end \$do\$. About dollar-quoting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12172353/939860

@ErwinBrandstetter $ is not a special character in strings in Rust, and usually sqlx migrations are included from text files, which are not processed specially at all anyway.

Yes, I tried with and without the semicolon, using escapes, and with a single quote and none of it worked.
